# Why can I not include a "£" symbol in my psychopy.visual.TextStim?

Tags: python, python-2.7, psychopy

I am currently trying to print a text stimulus using python 2.7.15 and Psychopy 1.90.2. Unfortanately the "£" symbol is causing the initialisation of visual.TextStim to throw an error:

```
money = 2
text_to_print = "£" + str(money)
bonus = visual.TextStim(win, text=text_to_print, pos=[0.7,-0.35], height=TEXT_STIM_HEIGHT, font="Arial", bold=True)
bonus.setColor('GoldenRod')
bonus.wrapWidth=1
```

The error reads:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc2 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I would like to know how I can incorporate a "£" symbol at the start of my text stimuli. Thank you.

Comment: Did you try to use a unicode string instead? `text_to_print = u"£" + unicode(money)`. Does it change anything?

Comment: I did indeed need the string as unicode. Thank you Giacomo Alzetta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prefix non-ascii characters with `u` (for "unicode") so:

```
text_to_print = u"£" + str(money)
```

When one character is unicode, others will be too, just like when you add integers and floats - the more comprehensive data type is chosen. The above is simpler than the more verbose equivalent:

```
text_to_print = "£" + str(money)  # Non-unicode; older libraries will go ahead and make it ascii
text_to_print.decode('utf-8')  # Use this. Libraries respect this (except the csv module)
```

From python3 and onwards (including PsychoPy3), everything is unicode by default so "special" characters should not pose a problem in PsychoPy.

Answer (score 4):

The error is explicit. `"£"` is not an ascii character. It is the unicode character U+00A3. As the error says that byte 0xc2 could not be decoded, I assume that your source is utf8 encoded (`"£"` reads as `b'\xc2\xa3'` when utf-8 encoded).

Not really sure of it because I have no python 2.7.15 and Psychopy 1.90.2 system, but I would try to pass an unicode string here:

```
bonus = visual.TextStim(win, text=text_to_print.decode('utf-8'), pos=[0.7,-0.35],
                        height=TEXT_STIM_HEIGHT, font="Arial", bold=True)
```